# splinter: faster way to find elements?

Tags: python, splinter

so I'm using the [python splinter library](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/) to test a web app and a problem I am running into is following when I am checking if an element exists and I'm manually finding each to manipulate it.

The problem is that when the inputs list gets bigger than 4 items or more and it runs into case when the element doesn't exist, it takes 12+ seconds to complete.

I also tried setting wait_time=1, but if inputs list is bigger than 10, it would take 10 times in total should the element not exist anywhere on the page.

```
for i in inputs:
    if browser.element_exists():
        elm = browser.find_element():
        elm.text()
```

I need some way to speed this up so that this element checking happens in parallel, without one by one. The only thing I can think of is executing javascript which I don't like (I'd like to keep it all in python).

```
def get_columns(current_depth,step,element):
    columns = []
    for xpath in xpaths:
        what = parse_xpath(row[2])
        if browser.is_element_present_by_xpath(xpath,wait_time=1):
            element = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath)
            columns.append(element.text)
        else:
            columns.append('none')
    return columns
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do all the inputs appear at the same time? Also, can you share the link so we can test it? Thanks.

Comment: @alexcxe yes, inputs are available. it's basically a list of xpaths. I am testing it out on this page, it takes forever to grab all the texts in the directory listing. If I did this in javascript it would've been done super fast but with splinter, it seems to wait everytime it fails to find something and it adds up. http://bit.ly/1p8dLrg

Comment: Thank you for the info. But can you also show the code you have so far? This would definitely help to help you to solve the issue.

Comment: @alecxe I added some code

Comment: What are your xpath ?

Answer (score 2):

[`is_element_present_by_xpath`](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/410f0ae72ab7a0701be9b8a7a27e480c4cc686f2/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L217) code is

```
def is_element_present_by_xpath(self, xpath, wait_time=None):
    return self.is_element_present(self.find_by_xpath, xpath, wait_time)
```

Using

```
def is_element_present(self, finder, selector, wait_time=None):
     wait_time = wait_time or self.wait_time
     end_time = time.time() + wait_time
     while time.time() < end_time:
         if finder(selector):
             return True
     return False
```

and

```
def find_by_xpath(self, xpath, original_find=None, original_query=None):
    original_find = original_find or "xpath"
    original_query = original_query or xpath
    return self.find_by(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath, 
                        xpath, 
                        original_find=original_find, 
                        original_query=original_query)
```

Your code basically seems to use the same function twice. Once you browse the list for testing if the element is in there by using `find_by_xpath` a first time, then you do it a second time for finding the element.

`find_by_xpath` returns an [ElementList](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/element-list.html#splinter.element_list.ElementList).

ElementList has a method `is_empty()` which returns True if it's empty aka no match.

So what about (I have not tested but answer from the top of my head).

```
def get_columns(current_depth,step,element):
    columns = []
    for xpath in xpaths:
        what = parse_xpath(row[2])
        element_list = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath)
        # You might want to check that your element_list has only 1 element.
        if element_list.is_empty():
            columns.append('none')
        else:
            columns.append(element_list[0].text)
    return columns
```

It would avoid to go through the list twice.

**UPDATE 2014-06-20:**

Going down the rabbit hole. Splinter is calling selenium wedriver… `self.find_by(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath, …` it's yet another level of inception. I'm not sure why they decided to do that instead of directly calling selenium in the first place.

Just for testing purpose, you should try first to use for this specific part of the code to use selenium directly and see if you notice a big difference in performance. That would discriminate if the performance issue comes from splinter or from selenium.

In selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py

```def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):
    """
    Finds multiple elements by xpath.

```
:Args:
 - xpath - The xpath locator of the elements to be found.

:Usage:
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'foo')]")
"""
return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

```

which is using:

```    def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
        """
        'Private' method used by the find_elements_by_* methods.

```
    :Usage:
        Use the corresponding find_elements_by_* instead of this.

    :rtype: list of WebElement
    """
    if not By.is_valid(by) or not isinstance(value, str):
        raise InvalidSelectorException("Invalid locator values passed in")

    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENTS,
                         {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
```

```

This last one is a direct call to the API through the JsonWireProtocol. Here performance are highly dependent on the implementations of Selenium on your system and/or browser if you are using one.

**UPDATE 2 2014-06-20:**

Also note that specifically for XPath, it really depends on the driver being used. The Selenium [documentation about this specific search](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath):

> At a high level, WebDriver uses a browser’s native XPath capabilities wherever possible. On those browsers that don’t have native XPath support, we have provided our own implementation. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour unless you are aware of the differences in the various xpath engines.

Comment: I will test this out and report tomorrow.

Comment: this did not make any improvements. The trouble is that when it encounters a missing element, it waits for a few seconds. I think the only way to pull this off is by using javascript

Comment: what is your xpath list? Have you tried with an xpath list of 1 item only.

Comment: @KJW Do you mean "when it doesn't match any elements" because "encounters a missing element" seems misleading? Also it would be good if you could add to your original post. A reduced markup and xpath you are trying to get.

Comment: Emptiness defines an ElementList's boolean value. `element_list.is_empty()` can be rewritten as `not element_list`